# Three.js: Inaccurate positioning of objects on screen while values are correct

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am building rows of differently shaped rectangles. They all have different widths and heights, but i already get them from a json object (in integers).

Now i need to bring them all on the same height, while mainting ratio and then aligning them in batches next to each other. E.g.:

```
var data = [{width:724,height:234},{width:345,height:726},{width:853,height:320}];
var xpos = 0;

for (var i=0, s=data.length; i<s; i+=1) {
    var materialBlack = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        ambient: 0x1b1b1b,
        color: 0x1b1b1b,
        overdraw: false,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
    var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialBlack );
    var scaleFactor = 300/data[i].height; // 300 units height for all
    var scaledWidth = data[i].width*scaleFactor;
    var scaledHeight = data[i].height*scaleFactor;
    xpos += i==0 ? 0 : scaledWidth;
    object.scale.set( scaledWidth, scaledHeight, 1);
    object.position.set( xpos, 0, 0 );
    scene.add( object );
}
```

Now the problem with this is that most of the rectangles sit neatly next to each other while a few are offset a little to the left or the right. And it is not just some one unit, more like a eighth of the whole rectangle.

While the visual result is off, logging the set values from the objects returns correct values and they all add up.

I have tried rounding the scale values but this doesn't make a difference. It always happens to the same objects though. I just can't identify a pattern here.

This is an example from the code and maybe someone can spot an obvious wrongdoing on my side. I am totally clueless how this can happen.

**JSFIDDLE**

Here's a fiddle. You'll need webgl and i only load the jsfiddle logo. but you will notice the overlaps in the flickering lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/7t2AM/2/

**UPDATE**

When i change the "scaleFactor" to always be 1 and align the rectangles in their unscaled size, they align properly. I am at my wit's end and i don't get while most are displayed correctly and just some are offset.

**UPDATE 2**

Here's a more complete copy of the code. Here i am not using 1x1 for the initial scaling of the rectangle but rather create it with the values i need in the end. Result is still the same though.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    Content.loadContent("en",function () {
        doStuff();
    });
});

var Config = {
    lang : "de",
    datahost : "http://localhost:3000/proxy?url=DATA_SOURCE_URL",
    imgproxy : "http://localhost:3000/imgproxy?url="
};

var objects = [];
var data;
var camera;
var scene;
var renderer;

function doStuff() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000 )

    data = Content.data;

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    camera.position.z = -1000;

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
    controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5;
    controls.maxDistance = 8000;
    controls.target.set(0,0,-2000);

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xeeeeee);
    ambientLight.castShadow = true;
    ambientLight.shadowCameraNear = 200;
    ambientLight.shadowCameraFar = camera.far;
    ambientLight.shadowCameraFov = 50;
    ambientLight.shadowBias = -0.00022;
    ambientLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
    ambientLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
    ambientLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    for ( var i= 0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
        var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(( Config.imgproxy ? Config.imgproxy : "" ) + data[i]["node"]["img"]);
        texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map: texture,
            overdraw: false,
            side: THREE.FrontSide
        });

        var width = parseInt(data[i]["node"]["img_width"]); // this is coming in as strings... sigh.
        var height = parseInt(data[i]["node"]["img_height"]);
        var scaleFactor = 300 / height;
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( width*scaleFactor, height*scaleFactor, 1, 1 );

        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object["nodeObject"] = data[i]["node"];

        scene.add( object );
        objects.push( object );
    }

    var xpos = 0;

    for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
        var object = objects[i];
        var height = parseInt(objects[i]["nodeObject"]["img_height"]);
        var scaleFactor = 300 / height;
        objects[i].position.set(xpos,0,-4000);
        xpos += (parseInt(objects[i]["nodeObject"]["img_width"])*scaleFactor);
    }

    animate();
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

var Content = {
    data : [],
    loadContent : function (lang,callback) {
        console.log("loading remote data");
        $.ajax(Config.datahost+"/"+lang+"/export/explore", {
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            success : function (data) {
                if (data["nodes"]) {
                    if (typeof data["nodes"]!=="array") {
                        if (typeof data["nodes"]==="object") {
                            Content.data = new Array();
                            for (var key in data["nodes"]) {
                                Content.data.push(data["nodes"][key]);
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log("unable to read data. neither array nor object");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Content.data = data["nodes"];
                    }
                };
                if (typeof callback==="function") callback();
            },
            error : function (xhr,stat,err) {
                console.log("error loading data - status: "+stat+" msg: "+err);
            }
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you put it up on a jsfiddle so we can see the full code and how it is acting?

Comment: the problem is that i can't give out the data source url and it loads all those images. maybe i can clean up the json data for posting.

Comment: here's the fiddle. you will notice the overlaps in those flickering lines. needs a webgl browser. and i can only load this one png from jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/7t2AM/1/

Comment: Where were you logging the results to console I don't see that in your jsfiddle. You probably just have a math error.

Comment: oh right that's not in there anymore. i'll update it in a moment.

Comment: not sure if the comment was shown, here's the jsfiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/7t2AM/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var width = parseInt( objects[ i ][ "nodeObject" ][ "img_width" ] ) * scaleFactor;

objects[ i ].position.set( xpos + ( width / 2 ), 0, 0 );

xpos += width;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7t2AM/4/

Also, in the future, please try to ask questions that are helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the size of `PlaneGeometry` is 2, and you are expecting it to be 1.

Try with this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1 );
```

Also, you can create just one geometry and material and reuse them in every mesh.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! but this only makes them half the size. also, is this the same as here in the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/7t2AM/2/ there i am creating the plane with units equal to the images pixel dimensions. it's just so weird that they overlap just a bit and not in 0.5 proportions or something.